# abi::__cxa_demangle can't reuse memory returned by itself

Tags: c++, gcc, memory, memory-management, clang

I tried to use `abi::__cxa_demangle` to demangle user-defined types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <cxxabi.h>

namespace
{

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wglobal-constructors"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wexit-time-destructors"
std::mutex m;
std::unique_ptr< char, decltype(std::free) & > demangled_name{nullptr, std::free};
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

}

inline
std::string
get_demangled_name(char const * const symbol) noexcept
{
    if (!symbol) {
        return "<null>";
    }
    std::lock_guard< std::mutex > lock(m);
    int status = -4;
    demangled_name.reset(abi::__cxa_demangle(symbol, demangled_name.release(), nullptr, &status));
    return ((status == 0) ? demangled_name.get() : symbol);
}

template< typename ...types >
void
f(std::size_t const i)
{
    using F = void (*)();
    assert(i < sizeof...(types));
    static F const a[sizeof...(types)] = {static_cast< F >([] () { std::cout << get_demangled_name(typeid(types).name()) << std::endl; })...};
    return a[i]();
};

struct A {};
struct B {};
struct X {};
struct Y {};
struct Z {};

int
main()
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
       f< A, B, X, Y, Z >(i);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But `abi::__cxa_demangle` returns `status` [*"-3: One of the arguments is invalid."*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html) every second time.

At the first call (for `A`) smart pointer contains `nullptr` and `abi::__cxa_demangle` returns zero `status` [*"0: The demangling operation succeeded."*](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a01696.html). But documentation said:

> output_buffer: A region of memory, allocated with malloc, of *length bytes, into which the demangled name is stored. If output_buffer is not long enough, it is expanded using realloc. output_buffer may instead be NULL; in that case, the demangled name is placed in a region of memory allocated with malloc.

Hence, I conclude the function can't reuse memory consistently allocated by itself. Is it bug or just my misunderstanding of the documentation?

Comment: Example code is for `clang++`, [but `g++` reproduce the results](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a14a6ed67be9d7a6).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood the docs:

> output_buffer: A region of memory, allocated with malloc, of *length bytes

You are passing a region of memory allocated with `malloc`, but `length` is null so `*length` is not defined.

In order to know whether it can re-use the memory it needs to know how large the block is, so you need to pass in the length as the third parameter.

The implementation in GCC (actually in the [libiberty support library](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/libiberty/cp-demangle.c?view=markup#l6020)) does:

```
  if (output_buffer != NULL && length == NULL)
    {
      if (status != NULL)
        *status = -3;
      return NULL;
    }
```

So if you pass a non-null `output_buffer` pointer you must also pass a non-null `length` pointer.

Since you don't know how large the allocated block is, the best you can do with the current code is use `strlen(demangled_name.get())+1` to find the minimum length that was definitely allocated.

Better would be to keep a `size_t` global that stores the previous size, and pass that in.  You should probably wrap that all up in a class, not just a bunch of globals.

Comment: Wrapping into the class is just a wrapping, I still have to provide a global instance of that class.

Comment: Yes, but it's called encapsulation and is useful :-) The point is to have one,  cohesive global, not three separate variables that just happen to be used together.

Answer (score 0):

To demangle under gcc use this code. It is reliable.

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
std::string demangle(T& e)
{
    int status;
    std::unique_ptr<char> realname;
    const std::type_info  &ti = typeid(e);
    realname.reset(abi::__cxa_demangle(ti.name(), 0, 0, &status));
    assert(status == 0);
    return std::string(realname.get());
}
```

Comment: It is clear to do in such a way, but my intention is to reuse `realloc`-ated memory by multiple threads (mutex and global smart pointer to storage intended exactly for this purpose).

Comment: This version uses only variables on the stack which are nowhere shared. So they are located in the scope of the calling thread. No Need for a mutex.

Comment: The title imply reusing of the memory.

Comment: **THIS IS NOT RELIABLE!** The pointer returned by `__cxa_demangle` MUST be deallocated with `free()` and not with the default deleter of `std::unique_ptr`.